# jQuery UI slider maximum

Tags: jquery-ui

There is a slider. When initializing it gets max:1, step:0.1.
But after changing the value it gets maximum to 0.9
The code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/8y7Hz/4/

html:

```
<div class="graph_slider" id="a"></div>
<div id="slider_val"></div>
```

js:

```
function sliderCange(){
    var s_val = $(this).slider("value");
    $('#slider_val').html(s_val);
}

$(document).ready(function(){    
    $('.graph_slider').each(function() {$(this).slider(
                                                    {
                                                        animate:true,
                                                        slide: sliderCange,
                                                        range: "min",
                                                        max: 1,
                                                        step: 0.1
                                                    });
                                       });
    $('.graph_slider').slider('option','value',1);
    var s_val = $('.graph_slider').slider("value");
    $('#slider_val').html(s_val);
});
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was your `slide` handler.

It works if you use:

```
function sliderChange(event, ui){
    $( "#slider_val" ).html(ui.value );
}
```

and

```
slide: function(event, ui) { sliderChange(event, ui); }
```

jsfiddle updated.